# MS ACCESS Query with junction table, for all items in one table, but not in another

Tags: sql, ms-access

To create a many-to-many relationship, I have three tables:

`tblEmployee`, contains employees

`tlkpPermission`, contains 11 different possible permission groups an employee can be part of

`tblEmployeeXPermission`, combines the `EmployeeID` with one or more `PermissionID`

What I’m trying to create is a query that shows what permission groups an employee is NOT part of.

So, if `EmployeeID` `12345` is associated with `PermissionID` `1,2,3,4,5,` but NOT `6,7,8,9,10,11` (in the `EmployeeXPermission` table) then I want the query to show `EmployeeID` `12345` is not part of PermissionID `6,7,8,9,10,11`.

Of all the JOINs and query options, I can only get a query to show which `PermissionIDs` an employee is associated with, but not the `PermissionIDs` the employee is not associated with.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with all combinations of employees and permissions, and this type of join is `CROSS JOIN`, but MsAccess SQL does not have it in the new SQL syntax. You can use the old syntax of listing your tables in the `FROM` clause, comma separated, and provide the join condition, if any, in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
  EmployeeId,
  PermissionID
FROM 
     tblEmployee as E,
     tlkpPermission as P
where not exists (
       select 1 
       from tblEmployeeXPermission X 
       where X.EmployeeId=E.EmployeeId 
       and X.PermissionId=P.PermissionId
       )
```

Here the part up to the `WHERE` clause would give you all employee - permission combinations, and the `WHERE` clause removes those occuring in the tblEmployeeXPermission, leaving you with the ones you want.